Android Glance Widget Error: Truncated Column container from 11 to 10 elements - IllegalArgumentException
I get the following Error when building my GlanceWidget.
Full StackTrace:
Truncated Column container from 11 to 10 elements
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Column container cannot have more than 10 elements
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.LayoutSelectionKt.insertContainerView-nVsUan0(LayoutSelection.kt:384)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateEmittableColumn(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:368)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateChild(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:221)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.setChildren(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:470)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateEmittableBox(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:313)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateChild(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:218)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.setChildren(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:470)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateEmittableRow(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:349)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateChild(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:220)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.setChildren(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:470)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateEmittableColumn(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:386)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateChild(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:221)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.setChildren(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:470)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateEmittableColumn(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:386)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateChild(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:221)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.setChildren(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:470)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateEmittableBox(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:313)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateChild(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:218)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.setChildren(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:470)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateEmittableBox(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:313)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateChild(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:218)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateEmittableSizeBox(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:262)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateChild(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:245)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateComposition(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:118)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.RemoteViewsTranslatorKt.translateComposition-KpG6l20(RemoteViewsTranslator.kt:76)
        at androidx.glance.appwidget.AppWidgetSession.processEmittableTree(AppWidgetSession.kt:174)
        at androidx.glance.session.SessionWorkerKt$runSession$4$1.invokeSuspend(SessionWorker.kt:210)
        at androidx.glance.session.SessionWorkerKt$runSession$4$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
        at androidx.glance.session.SessionWorkerKt$runSession$4$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__MergeKt$mapLatest$1.invokeSuspend(Merge.kt:213)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__MergeKt$mapLatest$1.invoke(Unknown Source:13)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__MergeKt$mapLatest$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowTransformLatest$flowCollect$3$1$2.invokeSuspend(Merge.kt:30)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowTransformLatest$flowCollect$3$1$2.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowTransformLatest$flowCollect$3$1$2.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startCoroutineUndispatched(Undispatched.kt:27)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:90)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:123)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:52)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source:1)

I've read that you have a maximum of 10 childs in a row or colummn in a remote view. - Source
I couldn't identify a point in my program where thats the case.
